# Create a random order of (x, y) pairs, without repeating/subsequent x's

Tags: python

Say I have a list of valid `X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and a list of valid `Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`.

I need to generate all combinations of every element in `X` and every element in `Y` (in this case, 25) and get those combinations in random order.

This in itself would be simple, but there is an additional requirement: In this random order, there cannot be a repetition of the same `x` in succession. For example, this is okay:

```
[1, 3]
[2, 5]
[1, 2]
...
[1, 4]
```

This is not:

```
[1, 3]
[1, 2]  <== the "1" cannot repeat, because there was already one before
[2, 5]
...
[1, 4]
```

Now, the least efficient idea would be to simply randomize the full set as long as there are no more repetitions. My approach was a bit different, repeatedly creating a shuffled variant of `X`, and a list of all `Y * X`, then picking a random next one from that. So far, I've come up with this:

```
import random

output = []
num_x  = 5
num_y  = 5

all_ys = list(xrange(1, num_y + 1)) * num_x

while True:
    # end if no more are available
    if len(output) == num_x * num_y:
        break

    xs = list(xrange(1, num_x + 1))
    while len(xs):
        next_x = random.choice(xs)
        next_y = random.choice(all_ys)

        if [next_x, next_y] not in output:
            xs.remove(next_x)
            all_ys.remove(next_y)
            output.append([next_x, next_y])

print(sorted(output))
```

But I'm sure this can be done even more efficiently or in a more succinct way?

Also, my solution first goes through all `X` values before continuing with the full set again, which is not *perfectly* random. I can live with that for my particular application case.

Comment: Do all values of `x` appear exactly once or at most once?

Comment: why `list(xrange ...` over `range`,  and also why not `while len(output)<num_xy` ?

Comment: @JohnColeman Every `x` will appear `len(Y)` times.

Comment: @M.T Because apparently I'm ignorant to Python idioms :P — haven't been doing much with this language, I'm afraid. But thanks for the pointers.

Comment: I see now -- you original question wasn't quite clear about that, though the edit makes it clear. Do you want all such orderings to appear with equal probability?

Comment: @JohnColeman Not necessarily. My current script indeed forces all elements in `X` to be processed before starting again, which is not perfectly random, but I can live with it.

Comment: How large are len(X) and len(Y) typically?  Don't immediately discard the simple, obvious, readable, and inefficient solution if the scale is small.

Comment: This is relevant: If len(X) = 4 and len(Y) = 13, then you are in effect looking for a shuffle of a deck in which no two consecutive cards have the same suit. The probability is known to be small: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/889415/probability-that-shuffled-deck-contains-no-two-consecutive-cards-of-the-same-sui . Thus -- a hit and miss approach is probably dead in the water.

Comment: @JohnColeman Aww, no BOGO sort? There goes my answer.

Comment: Does the case `len(X) == 2` ever arise? If so, that one should probably have a special-case algorithm since the constraints force a strict alternation in the first coordinate.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think my solution copes with `len(X) == 2`

Comment: @wim Doubtless a general solution would cope with that, but if Y is large even though X is small, a special-case algorithm for it might be much more efficient, though the case might be too rare to worry about.

Comment: @shlick : your solution returns incorrect results sometimes, I ran it a few times and saw duplicates in the first index.

Comment: @wim Interesting – do you know why it would be incorrect though? Maybe I didn't think this algorithm through enough. Also, the length typically is less than 10 for both X and Y, but how this degenerates would also be interesting.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this question. For an engineer transitioning into programming, I've spent 2 hours with 6 attempts so far trying to get around the brute-force aspect by having an `if` check, almost certainly in a misguided way, but I've learned more about programming from this question than any other :)

Answer (score 2):

An interesting question!  Here is my solution.  It has the following properties:

- If there is no valid solution it should detect this and let you know
- The iteration is guaranteed to terminate so it should never get stuck in an infinite loop
- Any possible solution is reachable with nonzero probability

I do not know the distribution of the output over all possible solutions, but I think it should be uniform because there is no obvious asymmetry inherent in the algorithm.  I would be surprised and pleased to be shown otherwise, though!

```
import random

def random_without_repeats(xs, ys):
    pairs = [[x,y] for x in xs for y in ys]
    output = [[object()], [object()]]
    seen = set()
    while pairs:
        # choose a random pair from the ones left
        indices = list(set(xrange(len(pairs))) - seen)
        try:
            index = random.choice(indices)
        except IndexError:
            raise Exception('No valid solution exists!')
        # the first element of our randomly chosen pair
        x = pairs[index][0]
        # search for a valid place in output where we slot it in
        for i in xrange(len(output) - 1):
            left, right = output[i], output[i+1]
            if x != left[0] and x != right[0]:
                output.insert(i+1, pairs.pop(index))
                seen = set()
                break
        else:
            # make sure we don't randomly choose a bad pair like that again
            seen |= {i for i in indices if pairs[i][0] == x}
    # trim off the sentinels
    output = output[1:-1]
    assert len(output) == len(xs) * len(ys)
    assert not any(L==R for L,R in zip(output[:-1], output[1:]))
    return output


nx, ny = 5, 5       # OP example
# nx, ny = 2, 10      # output must alternate in 1st index
# nx, ny = 4, 13      # shuffle 'deck of cards' with no repeating suit
# nx, ny = 1, 5       # should raise 'No valid solution exists!' exception

xs = range(1, nx+1)
ys = range(1, ny+1)

for pair in random_without_repeats(xs, ys):
    print pair
```

Comment: Unless `len(X) < 2` there is always a valid solution since you can simply cycle in the first coordinate. If your algorithm gets into an infinite loop, maybe some sort of back-tracking could be used to break out of the loop.

Comment: Is it possible for my algorithm to get stuck in an infinite loop, if a valid solution exists?  I can not see any way at a glance, but as I mentioned I'm not 100% sure either

Comment: Yes, in theory you can get stuck if you're very unlucky. You always choose the next pair randomly, come hell or high water. So for example, if the gods of chance decide to *always* "randomly" choose pairs with the same `x` value, then you can only insert the first pair and thereafter you are stuck. Obviously this is ludicrously unlikely, but it is mathematically possible. (Chances of this happening are higher if you are using a custom build of Python which relies on [this randomization function](https://xkcd.com/221/).)

Comment: The efficiency of your algorithm does vary with the sizes of `xs` and `ys`. When `xs` has just 2 elements and `ys` is very large, your algorithm spends a lot of time "throwing back" pairs that it cannot insert (and has more opportunity to get stuck in an infinite loop, though this is always a negligible chance in the real world).

Comment: Oh, I'm not worried about that case at all, since it has probability equal to 0.  That's as good as "impossible" for me.  I was more worried about the possibility that a solution exists which requires a re-ordering of the items already added into the output.  If an element is added to the output before [after] an existing element in the output, it will forever remain before [after] in that ordering - even if other elements are slotted in between.  I don't believe this could break the algorithm, but I can't prove that.

Comment: It was trivial to modify my idea so that it is guaranteed to terminate, therefore I have done so.

Comment: The probability of what I was describing wasn't zero, otherwise I wouldn't have called it "mathematically possible".

Comment: Yes, the probability is equal to 0.  If it's not 0, then tell me what number it is?

Comment: The number depends on a lot of things, including the size of `xs` and the size of `ys`. Different input sizes have different probabilities for infinite loops (as was implied by my second comment). But in any case, it's a very, very small positive number, close to but not exactly equal to zero. If it was **exactly** equal to zero, then why did you bother modifying your algorithm to prevent it from happening? By definition, probably of exactly zero means it can't happen.

Comment: I modified the algorithm so that now it has a guaranteed upper bound on the running time.  OK, I will make it simpler for you.  Let's suppose `xs = [0, 1]` and `ys = [0, 1]`.  Now tell me what is the probability that the [previous version of the] algorithm never terminates?  I reiterate to you that it is **exactly equal to 0**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108996/discussion-between-john-y-and-wim).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. First the tuples are chosen among the ones who have a different x value from the previous selected tuple. But I ve noticed that you have to prepare the final trick for the case you have only bad value tuples to place at end.

```
import random

num_x = 5
num_y = 5

all_ys = range(1,num_y+1)*num_x
all_xs = sorted(range(1,num_x+1)*num_y)

output = []

last_x = -1

for i in range(0,num_x*num_y):

    #get list of possible tuple to place    
    all_ind    = range(0,len(all_xs))
    all_ind_ok = [k for k in all_ind if all_xs[k]!=last_x]

    ind = random.choice(all_ind_ok)

    last_x = all_xs[ind]
    output.append([all_xs.pop(ind),all_ys.pop(ind)])


    if(all_xs.count(last_x)==len(all_xs)):#if only last_x tuples,
        break  

if len(all_xs)>0: # if there are still tuples they are randomly placed
    nb_to_place = len(all_xs)
    while(len(all_xs)>0):
        place = random.randint(0,len(output)-1)
        if output[place]==last_x:
            continue
        if place>0:
            if output[place-1]==last_x:
                continue
        output.insert(place,[all_xs.pop(),all_ys.pop()])

print output
```

Comment: Seems to work, well done for a first post and welcome to stack overflow :)

Comment: Note that this works only on Python 2, unless you add `list()` calls to the `range()` calls.

Comment: There are some worrysome performance pitfalls in here though. `sorted()` is not needed; use `[x for x in range(1, num_x + 1) for y in range(num_y)]` instead to produce the same output without. `all_xs.count()` has to traverse all of `all_xs` each iteration; that's 1/2 N loops each N times M iterations. That makes this an O(N**2) (quadratic) problem!

Comment: Ah, you also loop over all of `all_ind` anyway, so even without the `list.count()` this is a quadratic approach.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution  to ensure an average `O(N*M)` complexity:

```
def pseudorandom(M,N):
    l=[(x+1,y+1) for x in range(N) for y in range(M)]
    random.shuffle(l)
    for i in range(M*N-1):
            for j in range (i+1,M*N): # find a compatible ...
                if l[i][0] != l[j][0]:
                    l[i+1],l[j] = l[j],l[i+1]
                    break  
            else:   # or insert otherwise.
                while True:
                    l[i],l[i-1] = l[i-1],l[i]
                    i-=1
                    if l[i][0] != l[i-1][0]: break  
    return l
```

Some tests:

```
In [354]: print(pseudorandom(5,5))
[(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 1), (1, 1), (3, 2), (1, 2), (3, 5), (1, 5), (5, 4),\
(1, 3), (5, 2), (3, 4), (5, 3), (4, 5), (5, 5), (1, 4), (2, 5), (4, 4), (2, 4),\ 
(4, 2), (2, 1), (4, 3), (2, 3), (4, 1), (3, 3)]

In [355]: %timeit pseudorandom(100,100)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Your solution is not O(N\*M). You have a M\*N iteration loop, within which is another loop iterating up to M\*N times, followed by another M\*N worst case while loop. Sure, you *usually* break out of that inner loop, but the worst case is still O(NM**2).

Comment: I mentioned in average. From my test, 2M*N exchanges are roughly done each time.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using NumPy

```
def generate_pairs(xs, ys):
    n = len(xs)
    m = len(ys)
    indices = np.arange(n)

    array = np.tile(ys, (n, 1))
    [np.random.shuffle(array[i]) for i in range(n)]

    counts = np.full_like(xs, m)
    i = -1

    for _ in range(n * m):
        weights = np.array(counts, dtype=float)
        if i != -1:
            weights[i] = 0
        weights /= np.sum(weights)

        i = np.random.choice(indices, p=weights)
        counts[i] -= 1
        pair = xs[i], array[i, counts[i]]
        yield pair
```

Here's a [Jupyter notebook that explains how it works](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ProbablyOverthinkingIt/blob/master/shuffle_pairs.ipynb)

Inside the loop, we have to copy the weights, add them up, and choose a random index using the weights.  These are all linear in `n`.  So the overall complexity to generate all pairs is `O(n^2 m)`

But the runtime is deterministic and overhead is low.  And I'm fairly sure it generates all legal sequences with equal probability.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

`rando` will never generate the same X twice in a row, but I realized that it is *possible* (though seems unlikely, in that I never noticed it happen in the 10 or so times I ran without the extra check) that due to the potential discard of duplicate pairs it could happen upon a previous X. Oh! But I think I figured it out... will update my answer in a moment.

```
import random

X = [1,2,3,4,5]
Y = [1,2,3,4,5]


def rando(choice_one, choice_two):
    last_x = random.choice(choice_one)
    while True:
        yield last_x, random.choice(choice_two)
        possible_x = choice_one[:]
        possible_x.remove(last_x)
        last_x = random.choice(possible_x)


all_pairs = set(itertools.product(X, Y))
result = []
r = rando(X, Y)
while set(result) != all_pairs:
    pair = next(r)
    if pair not in result:
        if result and result[-1][0] == pair[0]:
            continue
        result.append(pair)

import pprint
pprint.pprint(result)
```

Comment: It can produce duplicates pairs in the output, the idea is to yield exactly 25 items here with no dupes and no repeats.

Comment: This too could produce an endless loop, as you randomly produce an already-produced pair over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

Distribute the `x` values (5 times each value) evenly across your output:

```
import random

def random_combo_without_x_repeats(xvals, yvals):
    # produce all valid combinations, but group by `x` and shuffle the `y`s
    grouped = [[x, random.sample(yvals, len(yvals))] for x in xvals]
    last_x = object()  # sentinel not equal to anything
    while grouped[0][1]:  # still `y`s left
        for _ in range(len(xvals)):
            # shuffle the `x`s, but skip any ordering that would
            # produce consecutive `x`s.
            random.shuffle(grouped)
            if grouped[0][0] != last_x:
                break
        else:
            # we tried to reshuffle N times, but ended up with the same `x` value
            # in the first position each time. This is pretty unlikely, but
            # if this happens we bail out and just reverse the order. That is
            # more than good enough.
            grouped = grouped[::-1]
        # yield a set of (x, y) pairs for each unique x
        # Pick one y (from the pre-shuffled groups per x
        for x, ys in grouped:
            yield x, ys.pop()
        last_x = x
```

This shuffles the `y` values per `x` first, then gives you *a* `x, y` combination for each `x`. The order in which the `x`s are yielded is shuffled each iteration, where you test for the restriction.

This is random, but you'll get all numbers between 1 and 5 in the `x` position before you'll see the same number again:

```
>>> list(random_combo_without_x_repeats(range(1, 6), range(1, 6)))
[(2, 1), (3, 2), (1, 5), (5, 1), (4, 1),
 (2, 4), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 5), (1, 4),
 (5, 2), (1, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (2, 5),
 (3, 5), (2, 3), (4, 2), (1, 2), (5, 4),
 (2, 2), (3, 4), (1, 3), (4, 5), (5, 3)]
```

(I manually grouped that into sets of 5). *Overall*, this makes for a pretty good random shuffling of a fixed input set with your restriction.

It is efficient too; because there is only a 1-in-*N* chance that you have to re-shuffle the `x` order, you should only see one reshuffle on average take place during a full run of the algorithm. The whole algorithm stays within O(N*M) boundaries therefor, pretty much ideal for something that produces *N* times *M* elements of output. Because we limit the reshuffling to N times at most before falling back to a simple reverse we avoid the (extremely unlikely) posibility of endlessly reshuffling.

The only drawback then is that it has to create *N* copies of the *M* y values up front.

Comment: The latter part is not a big problem; it's part of my solution as well. Of course it is not *perfectly* random, but I can live with this special case. (In fact, for my application, it would be preferred to "evenly" spread out the x's)

Comment: @slhck: there was a (very very very small) chance of an infinite loop in there. Now I just reverse the order of the group (one chance in N ** N this happens).

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I guess I will throw in the super-naive "just keep shuffling till you get one" solution. It's not guaranteed to even terminate, but if it does, it will have a good degree of randomness, and you did say one of the desired qualities was succinctness, and this sure is succinct:

```
import itertools
import random

x = range(5)  # this is a list in Python 2
y = range(5)
all_pairs = list(itertools.product(x, y))

s = list(all_pairs)  # make a working copy
while any(s[i][0] == s[i + 1][0] for i in range(len(s) - 1)):
    random.shuffle(s)
print s
```

As was commented, for small values of `x` and `y` (especially `y`!), this is actually a reasonably quick solution. Your example of 5 for each completes in an average time of "right away". The deck of cards example (4 and 13) can take much longer, because it will usually require hundreds of thousands of shuffles. (And again, is not *guaranteed* to terminate at all.)

Comment: Good thing that `product()` iterates over the `y`s first, otherwise your `any()` condition would never be true at the start and it'd never even attempt a shuffle! :-D

Comment: But yes, there is a random chance this never terminates. Somewhere, someone's machine is going to get real busy for a long, long time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Regarding the workings of `product()`: Indeed, if you don't care about randomness at all, and really just want a sequence satisfying the requirement that no consecutive pairs have the same `x` value, just doing `s = [(b, a) for (a, b) in product(y, x)]` and dispensing with the loop altogether is one way to do it both succinctly *and* quickly. ;)

Comment: This is the 'bogo' solution.  If the size of y grows while x stays small, the idea just stops working

Comment: @wim: I tried to be clear that this is (1) not a "serious" solution and (2) not even a viable solution for anything but small arguments. It's already damn nigh unusable for the deck of cards example I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an evolutionary algorithm approach. It first evolves a list in which the elements of `X` are each repeated `len(Y)` times and then it randomly fills in each element of `Y` len(X) times. The resulting orders seem fairly random:

```
import random

#the following fitness function measures
#the number of times in which
#consecutive elements in a list
#are equal

def numRepeats(x):
    n = len(x)
    if n < 2: return 0
    repeats = 0
    for i in range(n-1):
        if x[i] == x[i+1]: repeats += 1
    return repeats

def mutate(xs):
    #swaps random pairs of elements
    #returns a new list
    #one of the two indices is chosen so that
    #it is in a repeated pair
    #and swapped element is different

    n = len(xs)
    repeats = [i for i in range(n) if (i > 0 and xs[i] == xs[i-1]) or (i < n-1 and xs[i] == xs[i+1])]
    i = random.choice(repeats)
    j = random.randint(0,n-1)
    while xs[j] == xs[i]: j = random.randint(0,n-1)
    ys = xs[:]
    ys[i], ys[j] = ys[j], ys[i]
    return ys

def evolveShuffle(xs, popSize = 100, numGens = 100):
    #tries to evolve a shuffle of xs so that consecutive
    #elements are different
    #takes the best 10% of each generation and mutates each 9
    #times. Stops when a perfect solution is found
    #popsize assumed to be a multiple of 10

    population = []

    for i in range(popSize):
        deck = xs[:]
        random.shuffle(deck)
        fitness = numRepeats(deck)
        if fitness == 0: return deck
        population.append((fitness,deck))

    for i in range(numGens):
        population.sort(key = (lambda p: p[0]))
        newPop = []
        for i in range(popSize//10):
            fit,deck = population[i]
            newPop.append((fit,deck))
            for j in range(9):
                newDeck = mutate(deck)
                fitness = numRepeats(newDeck)
                if fitness == 0: return newDeck
                newPop.append((fitness,newDeck))
        population = newPop
    #if you get here :
    return [] #no special shuffle found

#the following function takes a list x
#with n distinct elements (n>1) and an integer k
#and returns a random list of length nk
#where consecutive elements are not the same

def specialShuffle(x,k):
    n = len(x)
    if n == 2:
        if random.random() < 0.5:
            a,b = x
        else:
            b,a = x
        return [a,b]*k
    else:
        deck = x*k
        return evolveShuffle(deck)

def randOrder(x,y):
    xs = specialShuffle(x,len(y))
    d = {}
    for i in x:
        ys = y[:]
        random.shuffle(ys)
        d[i] = iter(ys)

    pairs = []
    for i in xs:
        pairs.append((i,next(d[i])))
    return pairs
```

for example:

```
>>> randOrder([1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5])
[(1, 4), (3, 1), (4, 5), (2, 2), (4, 3), (5, 3), (2, 1), (3, 3), (1, 1), (5, 2), (1, 3), (2, 5), (1, 5), (3, 5), (5, 5), (4, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (5, 4), (2, 4), (4, 2), (1, 2), (5, 1), (4, 1), (3, 4)]
```

As `len(X)` and `len(Y)` gets larger this has more difficulty finding a solution (and is designed to return the empty list in that eventuality), in which case the parameters `popSize` and `numGens` could be increased. As is, it is able to find 20x20 solutions very rapidly. It takes about a minute when `X` and `Y` are of size 100 but even then is able to find a solution (in the times that I have run it).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting restriction!  I probably overthought this, solving a more general problem: shuffling an arbitrary list of sequences such that (if possible) no two adjacent sequences share a first item.

```
from itertools import product
from random import choice, randrange, shuffle

def combine(*sequences):
    return playlist(product(*sequences))

def playlist(sequence):
    r'''Shuffle a set of sequences, avoiding repeated first elements.
    '''#"""#'''
    result = list(sequence)
    length = len(result)
    if length < 2:
        # No rearrangement is possible.
        return result
    def swap(a, b):
        if a != b:
            result[a], result[b] = result[b], result[a]
    swap(0, randrange(length))
    for n in range(1, length):
        previous = result[n-1][0]
        choices = [x for x in range(n, length) if result[x][0] != previous]
        if not choices:
            # Trapped in a corner: Too many of the same item are left.
            # Backtrack as far as necessary to interleave other items.
            minor = 0
            major = length - n
            while n > 0:
                n -= 1
                if result[n][0] == previous:
                    major += 1
                else:
                    minor += 1
                if minor == major - 1:
                    if n == 0 or result[n-1][0] != previous:
                        break
            else:
                # The requirement can't be fulfilled,
                # because there are too many of a single item.
                shuffle(result)
                break

            # Interleave the majority item with the other items.
            major = [item for item in result[n:] if item[0] == previous]
            minor = [item for item in result[n:] if item[0] != previous]
            shuffle(major)
            shuffle(minor)
            result[n] = major.pop(0)
            n += 1
            while n < length:
                result[n] = minor.pop(0)
                n += 1
                result[n] = major.pop(0)
                n += 1
            break
        swap(n, choice(choices))
    return result
```

This starts out simple, but when it discovers that it can't find an item with a different first element, it figures out how far back it needs to go to interleave that element with something else.  Therefore, the main loop traverses the array at most three times (once backwards), but usually just once.  Granted, each iteration of the first forward pass checks each remaining item in the array, and the array itself contains every pair, so the overall run time is `O((NM)**2)`.

For your specific problem:

```
>>> X = Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> combine(X, Y)
[(3, 5), (1, 1), (4, 4), (1, 2), (3, 4),
 (2, 3), (5, 4), (1, 5), (2, 4), (5, 5),
 (4, 1), (2, 2), (1, 4), (4, 2), (5, 2),
 (2, 1), (3, 3), (2, 5), (3, 2), (1, 3),
 (4, 3), (5, 3), (4, 5), (5, 1), (3, 1)]
```

By the way, this compares x values by equality, not by position in the X array, which may make a difference if the array can contain duplicates.  In fact, duplicate values might trigger the fallback case of shuffling all pairs together if more than half of the X values are the same.